# Windows automatically change to Ubuntu while lock screen

Tags: dual-boot

I currently have dual OS, Windows 10 and Ubuntu, on two seperate hard drive. While I was using Window, after a short time, it lock screen and when I log in again, the Ubuntu shown and I have no idea how to get back to window to finish my job. 
I found many topic and it seems that no one have the same problem as me.
Can anyone help me with that? Or a link to related issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can imagine this can have happened is if Ubuntu is set to boot first, and Windows for some reason decided to reboot. If this is the case, a simple reboot, and selecting Windows in the boot loader should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any way to prevent this completely ? I mean this is really annoying when I leave my desk for lunch at work and when I came back it change to Ubuntu.

Comment: Blame Windows for randomly rebooting. It loves to do that after updates or for some other reasons. What you could do would be to configure GRUB so that it boot the last started OS by default, but I personally find that confusing.